# After using __str__, Tkinter still shows repl <xxx object at location xxxxxxxxx>

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'm learning Python through the course and the assignment was to write an [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) quiz application.

> I wanted to make a Tkinter GUI where from the main window you chose
>  one of the three lengths (10, 25 50 questions) and each closes the
>  main window records a number of questions and writes it in txt for
>  data to read, and then you just complete the quiz.
>  But it was showing repr (when it was printing in the terminal) when
>  it shouldn't. I browsed a bit and found `__str__` and it was ok.
>  Then I made as Tkinter GUI, but the problem returned and `__str__` isn't
>  helping and I don't know what to do anymore.

Old prompt under spoilers.

When I run the code, I expect that after choosing the length of the quiz, it will close the current window and open the quiz window with the text of the question, but it shows repr.

[Main window where you choose length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iorh9.png)
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaIuw.png)

The problem is in the Ui class somewhere, because when I tested other modules, it worked as it should (printing answers in the terminal), but when it gets to the Ui stage it breaks.

This is: data. py, works

```
import requests
import json

with open("quizztype.txt", "r") as qt:
    value = qt.readline()

parameters = {
    "amount": value,
    "type": "boolean",
}

response = requests.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php",
params=parameters)
# response.raise_for_status()

question_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

This is: main.py, and it works

```
from question_model import Question
from data import question_data
from quiz_brain import QuizBrain
from ui import Ui
import html

question_bank = []
for question in question_data['results']:
    question_text = html.unescape(question['question'])
    question_answer = question['correct_answer']
    new_question = Question(question_text, question_answer)
    question_bank.append(str(new_question))

quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)
ui = Ui(QuizBrain)
```

This is: question_model.py, and it works

```
class Question:

    def __init__(self, q_text: str, q_answer: str):
        self.text = q_text
        self.answer = q_answer

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Q.{self.text}: {self.answer}"
```

This is: quiz_brain.py, and it works, but it might be the problem.

```
from question_model import Question
from data import question_data
from ui import Ui
import html

class QuizBrain:

    def __init__(self, q_list: list):
        self.question_number = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.question_list = q_list
        self.current_question = None
        self.what_to_return = str


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        self.what_to_return = str(f"Q.{self.question_number}: {self.current_question}")
        return self.what_to_return


    def still_has_questions(self):
        return self.question_number < len(self.question_list)

"""This could be a problematic part"""
    def next_question(self):
        self.current_question = str(self.question_list[self.question_number])
        self.question_number += 1
        self.what_to_return = str(f"Q.{str(self.question_number)}: {str(self.current_question)}")
        return self.what_to_return

# self.check_answer(user_answer)

    def check_answer(self, user_answer):
        correct_answer = self.current_question
        if user_answer.lower() == correct_answer.lower():
            self.score += 1
            print("You got it right!")
        else:
            print("That's wrong.")

        print(f"Your current score is: {self.score}/{self.question_number}")
        print("\n")
```

And last is the Tkinter GUI.

I think that the way I did it is probably stupid, but I don't know better and didn't find better.
And I think that somewhere here is the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk

score = 0
THEME_COLOR = "#375362"

class Ui():

    def __init__(self, quiz_brain) -> None:

        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.quiz = quiz_brain
        self.window.minsize(width=300, height=300)
        self.window.config(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.window.title('Quizz Game')

        self.label_10_questions = tk.Label(text='Quizz that contains 10 questions')
        self.label_10_questions.place(x=50,y=30)
        self.questions_button_10 = tk.Button(text='select',command= self.game_ui_10 )
        self.questions_button_10.place(x=115, y= 75)
        self.highscore_10 = tk.Label(text= f'highscore        {score}')
        self.highscore_10.place(x=50, y=50)
        self.button_exit = tk.Button(text= 'Exit', command=self.window.destroy)
        self.button_exit.place(x=250, y= 250)
        self.window.mainloop()

"""potential problem and anywhere it's used"""
    def next_question_correct(self):
        q_text = str(self.quiz.next_question)
        canvas.itemconfig(str(question_text), text=str(q_text))


    def game_ui_10(self,):
        global canvas
        global question_text
        self.window.destroy()
        with open("quizztype.txt", "w") as qt:
            qt.write("10")

        window = tk.Tk()
        window.minsize(width=500, height=400)
        window.config(padx=10, pady=10, bg=THEME_COLOR)
        window.title('Quizz Game')

        canvas = tk.Canvas(width=450, height=150, bg='white')
        canvas.place(x=15, y=60)
        question_text = canvas.create_text(200,75, text= "x", fill=THEME_COLOR, font=("Arial",20, "italic"), width=400)
        true_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/true.png")
        false_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/false.png")
        true_button = tk.Button(image= true_image, highlightthickness=0, command=self.next_question_correct)
        true_button.place(x= 15, y= 260)
        false_button = tk.Button(image=false_image, highlightthickness=0, command=self.next_question_correct)
        false_button.place(x=350, y= 260)

        score_label = tk.Label(text=f"Score {0}/{0}", bg= THEME_COLOR, fg="white", font=("Arial",15, "normal"))
        score_label.place(x= 350, y= 10)

        str(self.next_question_correct())
        window.mainloop()
        ui = Ui(self.quiz)
```

Because I'm learning, I just browsed the Internet and found that `__repr__` or `__str__` can help with converting `<xxxx object at location xxxxx>` to normal text, so that is what I used. I don't know what else I could do.

Comment: It's not `__repl__` it's called `__repr__`. However your question isn't clear. Please try to reduce your code to a [mre]. Where do you expect something else and what else do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this addresses the issue with the **str** but instead of passing the class itself, create an instance of QuizBrain and pass it to the Ui class.

main.py:

```
quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)
ui = Ui(QuizBrain)
```

to this:

```
quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)
ui = Ui(quiz)
```

Comment: Tried that and now it writes <bound method QuizBrain.next_question of <quiz_brain.QuizBrain boject at 0x0000xxxxxxxxx>>